# How would I get write this query in cakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to write the following query in cakePHP 2.x

```
SELECT u.username, s.code
   FROM users u
     LEFT JOIN skills_users su ON su.user_id = u.id
     LEFT JOIN skills s ON s.id = su.skill_id
   WHERE s.id =2
```

I do not want to use $this-Model->query("....");

I have tried the following using the cakePHP Linkable behaviour (https://github.com/lorenzo/linkable) as suggested by the guys in the #cakephp in IRC but it seems my condition is being ignored.

```
        $user = $this->User->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array(
                'Skill',
            ),
            'link' => array('Skill' => array('conditions' => array('Skill.id' => 2), 'type' =>         'inner'))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using JOINS per the book?:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables